# Parallax Gyro work on Turtlebot 1?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, gyro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've built my own Turtlebot using the iRobot create and xBox Kinect. I have the latest ROS installed and running. I picked up a **Parallax Gyroscope Module 3-Axis L3G4200D:** ([www.parallax.com/product/27911](http://www.parallax.com/product/27911)) from my local RadioShack and wanted to know if it will work with the ROS software. I found this post: **Is an IMU required to run Turtlebot stack?:** (//answers.ros.org/question/9749/is-an-imu-required-to-run-turtlebot-stack/?answer=14244#post-id-14244) and was wondering if it would connect to the create the same way.

I've been building this to learn programming/robotics and pretty good at following directions. But don't have the knowledge to start from scratch yet. I want to think everyone that shares their projects and code. It really helps us newcomers getting started.

**1/9/14 UPDATE:** Would this be the correct connections for this gyro if ROS supports it?
([www.digikey.com/schemeit/embed/#lz6](http://www.digikey.com/schemeit/embed/#lz6))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115741/parallax-gyro-work-on-turtlebot-1?/) by [rleigh](https://answers.ros.org/users/10556/rleigh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One the Turtlebot1, the [original gyro](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9059) was attached to one of the analog input pins on the Create.

To determine if your gyro is compatible, you'll need to check a few things:

- Does it use the same power supply voltage as the original gyro? (5V)
- Does it have an analog output pin?
- Does the analog output have the same magnitude as the original gryo? The original gyro specifies 12.5 mV/degree/sec

If you find a compatible gyro, make sure that the axis that you hook up to the Turtlebot's analog input pin is the vertical axis.

EDIT:

The gyro you've picked out is a digital gyro, and won't be compatible with the Turtlebot1.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rleigh](https://answers.ros.org/users/10556/rleigh/) on 2014-01-09**:
ahendrix, thanks for the reply. I misunderstood the description of this gyro. I thought that it could be wired as a digital or analog ( three or four ) wire setup. I'll look for an analog gyro. Thanks again for your time.